# DataRow created by DataTable.NewRow() can't be accessed through BindingManager.Position

Tags: c#, data-binding, datatable

Sorry for my bad English, hope you can understand my situation.
A table in database will be shown in TextBoxs from a Form with DataBinding, like the following:

```
DataTable dataTable = dataBase.ReadTable(tableName); //Suppose: dataTable.Rows.Count == 10
BindingManagerBase bindingManager = BindingContext[dataTable];
BindTextBoxsWith(dataTable);
ActionToChange(bindingManager.Position);
```

Everthing works fine. Then I need to add a new row and switch to the new row for editing, so these code are added:

```
DataRow dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();
dataRow[primaryKey] = 0;
dataTable.Add(dataRow);
bindingManager.Position = dataTable.Rows.Count - 1; //value in breakpoint: dataTable.Rows.Count == 11, bindingManager.Position == 0
```

As shown in the comment, the BindingManager's Position don't work in a normal style. How can it be? 
Then I try these code:

```
dataTable = dataTable.Copy();
BindTextBoxsAgainWith(dataTable);
bindingManager = BindingContext[dataTable];
```

Now *bindingManager.Position* can work, but the problem is when *bindingManager.Position* changes, a same row is bound everytime.

What caused this problem? Expect your help.

Comment: Are you binding your `dataTable` to a control? How? Via a `BindingSource`?

Comment: I bind the datatable fields to many TextBox control with simply databinding, like: textBoxSample.DataBindings.Add("Text", dataTable, fieldName, false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);